# How to solve this error: Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE): cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame

Tags: r

I am using RStudio, Version 1.3.1073 on a Mac.

I have the following code

```
    # Clear R-Environment
rm(list = ls())

# Load necessary packages
library("readxl")
library("openxlsx")
library("xlsx")


# Set working directory
setwd("C:/Users/PN/Dropbox/Economics/Projects/HN_Hidden Debt/_data/WB_GDF/GDF 2004-1997 Excel Spreadsheet")

filename <- "GDF 2004 Excel Spreadsheet.xlsx"
filename_new <- "GDF 2004 new.xlsx"
split_pre <- "Memo: IBRD"

split_1 <- "Memo:"
split_2 <- "IBRD"


file <- file.path(getwd(), filename)
data <- read_excel(file, col_types = "text")

add_row <- c(rep(NA,ncol(data)))


data$`Country Tables 2002` <- trimws(data$`Country Tables 2002`)

x <- nrow(data)*1.25


for (i in 1:x) {
  
  if (!is.na(data[i,1])) {
    if (data[i,1] == as.character(split_pre)) {
      j <- i + 1
      k <- nrow(data)
      data[i,1] <- split_1
      data <- rbind(data[1:i,], add_row, data[j:k,])
      data[j,1] <- split_2
      data[j,2:ncol(data)] <- data[i,2:ncol(data)]
      data[i,2:ncol(data)] <- NA
      cat(i)
      cat("\n")
    }
  }
}

write.xlsx(x = data, file = paste0(getwd(), "/", filename_new))
```

but the following errors keep on re-appearing:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :    cannot
> coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame.

And:

```
> data <- read_excel(file, col_types = "text")
```

> Error in read_excel(file, col_types = "text") :
> could not find function "read_excel"

I am using this code on the following data:

| Memo: IBRD |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IDA |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: are you sure you have run the codes that load the libraries before using `read_excel`?

Comment: I saw that in another forum and it otherwise gives me an error message for each of these libraries. But I could try it again without them.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). For `readxl` error use `readxl::read_excel`.

Comment: @gregthenovelist if you get an error when you load the libraries it is possible that these libraries are not installed in your system. See `?install.packages` for installing packages